# Загрузка JSON один раз в начале работы приложения

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Приложение на AngularJS. Есть корневой модуль:

```js
    angular.module('myApp', ['categoriesList'])
```

к которому подключен модуль categoriesList

```js
    angular.module('categoriesList', [])

    angular.module('categoriesList')
        .component('categoriesList', {
            templateUrl: 'categories-list/categories-list.template.html',
            controller: function CategoriesListController() {

            }
        })
```

Как загрузить данные JSON одни раз в начале приложения в модуле myApp, и затем передать их в другие модули.

Пробовал такой вариант, но т.к. данные приходят асинхронно, в categoriesList не присвоить результат:

```js
    angular.module('myApp', ['categoriesList'])
      .run(function ($http, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.isLoaded = false
        $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8887/base.json')
          .then(response => {
            $rootScope.data = response.data
            $rootScope.isLoaded = true
          })
      })
```

Кроме того $rootScope доступен в модуле categoriesList, но свойства не наследуются. Их нужно переопределять *$scope.load = $rootScope.isLoaded* (хотя насколько я понял, должны просто наследоваться)

html:

```html
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        ...
        <categories-list></categories-list>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил через промисы. В корневом модуле создается сервис:

```js
    .factory('httpservice', function ($q, $http) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve($http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8887/base.json'));
        return deferred.promise;
      })
```

Остальные модули используют его:

```js
    let promise = httpservice
    promise.then(function (resp) {
        $scope.categories = resp.data.categories })
```

Возможно есть решение через *$broadcast* и *$on*.